# Odoo 10 - How to include Python package dependency in __manifest__

Tags: odoo

If a new Odoo module requires a given Python package, is it needed or recommended to include that dependency in **manifest**.py as external dependency?

If so, how is that reference specifically included?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add external_dependencies in **manifest** file of module as following :

```
"external_dependencies": {"python": [name of library/python package,..]},
```

For more information : [See here](https://odoo-development.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/docs/__manifest__.py.html)

Comment: Link is broken... Should be http://odoo-development.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/docs/__manifest__.py.html